# how can show hex data on terminal like x0AA by using python

Tags: python, serial-port, hex

I wrote a code which gets data from a hardware device,but when it prints in terminal it shows like this: ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
how is it possible that shows above byte like 0xAA0x41 and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s=''
for c in '▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒':
   s=s+hex(ord(c))
print(s)
```

> '0x25920x25920x25920x25920x25920x25920x25920x2592'

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> print(hex(ord(b'a')))
0x61
```

Comment: I store each received hex in a byte so how can I convert that byte to something like 0xA and print it